# Delay in adding a vector table while QGIS scans for items

Tags: qgis

I am trying to add a MapInfo vector table (.tab) through the Data Source Manager. It is a large file that holds property boundary polygons for the State of Victoria in Australia (the .dat file is 1.4gb). In previous versions I would be able to selected the .tab file and may then have to wait for some time as it loads and renders into the map window, but it would eventually load within maybe 30 secs.
In recent versions of QGIS there is now an additional step with a dialog box headed 'Select items to add'. The program then states that it is scanning the file, presumably in case the file may have multiple tables (as in a geopackage file)? But this process then seems to hang ... or at least it goes on for many minutes as I have not had the patience to wait it out.
Is this a bug? Does a MapInfo table have the capacity to contain sub-tables within it? Should QGIS be scanning for tables to add in this way? Or is there a workaround to open the table without this 'scan' step?
[image: dialog box]

Comment: Do you get the same problem if you drag and drop the .tab file from File Explorer into the QGIS main window?

Comment: or use data from wms in QGIS? (https://maps.land.vic.gov.au/geolassi/wms?version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities)

Comment: @she_weeds yes the same thing happens with drag and drop. An update on my question - I did eventually wait it out - about 10 mins to display approx 3 million polygons

Comment: @Mapperz I haven't checked with wms but I need to obtain vector records for further selection and analysis so tiled images won't be useful

Comment: have you tried the VMPROP shapefiles instead of tab? I use PARCEL_VIEW and PROPERTY_VIEW for all of VIctoria fairly regularly and it doesn't take nearly as much time to load, although I am using m2 SSDs and have 32GB of RAM. If you are using a mechanical hard drive it would obviously be much slower

Comment: Thanks @she_weeds, yes I should try the shapefiles. But I guess part of my question was in wondering why there is this new stage in the process in recent versions of QGIS. But then, that is really a question to direct to the QGIS development team isn't it!